# While Loop with Switch Statement

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm having trouble getting the switch to constantly loop until user tells the program to stop. 
When the user is prompt to put in a N to loop, they should be sent back to the top of the switch

```
        char stop;
    while(stop == 'N'){
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter the time in seconds:");
                time = input.nextInt();
                displacement = (Math.pow(time,4)) + 16;
                System.out.println("Felix's displacement is equal to " + displacement + " meters");
                System.out.println("Stop the application(Y/N)");
                stop = input.findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter the time in seconds:");
                time = input.nextInt();
                velocity = 4*(Math.pow(time,3));
                System.out.println("Felix's velocity is equal to " + velocity + " m/s");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Enter the time in seconds:");
                time = input.nextInt();
                acceleration = 12*(Math.pow(time,2));
                System.out.println("Felix's acceleration is equal to " + acceleration + " m/(s*s)");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please select a choice");

        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of stop when you enter the loop ? Its not set hence it will not enter the loop. What is choice sent to ? You are not updating choice in your loop at all.

Comment: @StackFlowed: Well, more than that - it won't compile... it's not definitely assigned.

Comment: In addition to that what is the use of `switch` inside loop if `choice` never changed it will execute same case again and again

Answer (score 0):

1. Crudely: *initialise* `stop` on declaration:

`char stop = 'N';`

2. Better: replace your `while` with a `do` `while` loop:

   do {

   } while (stop == 'N')

Answer (score 0):

"stop" refers to an empty space in memory when you refer to it at the first go through your while loop, so it will never start.  You'll need to initialize it or rearrange your looping structure. Additionally, it seems like you need to prompt the user for "choice", unless that portion of the code has been removed.